# How to Create a New Table with Distinct Values but selecting the Max from another column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am using Python and SQLite, and I am trying to copy the table to another table. I have a column called InventoryNbr and I also have a column called IndexID. The other columns do not matter at this point but I would like to copy them as well.  There are several duplicates of InventoryNbr. I only want distinct Inventory Numbers, but I want the MAX IndexID. I keep using this, and getting the LOWEST IndexID. How can I change this to get the max IndexID?

```
masterCursor.execute('INSERT INTO MasterV2 SELECT InventoryNbr, IndexListID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, Extra FROM Master GROUP BY InventoryNbr ORDER BY IndexListID ASC')
```

edit:My table looks like:

```
InventoryNbrs | IndexListID
12345         | 123
12345         | 124
12345         | 125
12346         | 126
12346         | 127
12347         | 128
```

I want my new table to look like:

```
InventoryNbrs | IndexListID
12345         | 125
12346         | 127
12347         | 128
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It would really clarify your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO MasterV2 
SELECT InventoryNbr, MAX(IndexListID), col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, Extra 
FROM Master 
GROUP BY InventoryNbr
```

The above select statement returns for each `InventoryNbr` the row with the max `IndexListID`, taking advantage of a documented feature of SQLite.
You can find more here: [Simple Select Processing](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing)

Comment: PERFECT. This is very simple and worked. I believe I tried the MAX(IndexListID) before, but I did not have Group BY at the end and it only inserted 1 row into my new table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
INSERT INTO MasterV2   -- you should list the columns here
    SELECT InventoryNbr, IndexListID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, Extra
    FROM (SELECT m.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InventoryNbr ORDER BY IndexListID DESC) as seqnum
          FROM Master m
         ) m
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The `SELECT` returns one row per `InventoryNbr`.  The one row is the row with the largest value of `IndexListID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MasterV2
SELECT t.*
  FROM your_table t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.InventoryNbr = t.InventoryNbr and tt.IndexListID > t.IndexListID );
```